# How could I manage many vhosts with PHP-FPM and LIGHTTPD?

Tags: lighttpd, php-fpm

I have installed php5-fpm and lighttpd. I want to chroot the directory of each vhost.

I don't want one vhost can read other vhost's file. How to do it by FPM ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a separate pool of PHP processes for each user.  You would need to bind each one to a separate socket, and configure lighttpd to send requests to a different process depending on which vhost is being accessed.